# Object.keys does not render my view in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a view through an array Within
`Object.keys(data).map((section, i)` I have put `console.log ();` and they show the information that it should show, but nothing is painted. What am I doing wrong?

```
 let data={
    "trucker": {
        "section": "camionero"
    },
    "client": {
        "section": "cliente"
    }
}
const [data, setData] = useState(data);

                        return (<List>
                            {
                                Object.keys(data).map((section, i) => {
                                    console.log("*", section, " ", data[section].section);
                                    /* result of console.log()
                                     * trucker   camionero
                                     * client   cliente
                                     * container   contenedor
                                    */
                                    return
                                    <ListItem itemHeader first key={i}>
                                        <Text>{data[section].section}</Text>
                                    </ListItem>
                                })
                            }

                        </List>)
```

Comment: I suspect an ASI (automatic semicolon insertion) issue here as you put `<ListItem>` under the `return` statement. Either wrap your return value inside `()` or put `<ListItem>` on the same line as the `return` statement.

Comment: @customcommander If I make a consel.log () inside the first .map information is displayed. I don't know why the content inside it is not shown

Comment: Because you didn't put the return value __on__ the same line as the `return` statement, the `return` statement evaluates to `undefined`. To prevent that wrap your component inside `(` and `)` and put the opening paren __on__ the same line as the `return` statement.

Comment: it works! put please your answer

Comment: It's _exactly_ the same answer as @AlexWayne's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return
<ListItem itemHeader first key={i}>
  <Text>{data[section].section}</Text>
</ListItem>
```

The `return` keyword cannot be on its own line. JS interprets that as its own standalone statement and returns `undefined` instead of the value on the next line.

Add some parens to force it to return your JSX.

```
return (
  <ListItem itemHeader first key={i}>
    <Text>{data[section].section}</Text>
  </ListItem>
)
```

[Further relevant reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Comment: If I make a consel.log () inside the first .map information is displayed. I don't know why the content inside it is not shown